# Why does returning false in the keydown callback does not stop the button click event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, keyboard

I have a button and the following javascript routine.

```
$("button").keydown( function(key) {
  switch(key.keyCode) {
  case 32: //space
    return false;
  }
} );
```

as I understood it, the `return false;` would stop the keypress from being processed. So `$("button").click();` would not be called. For other keyCodes, this works as expected. For example, if I intercept`40`, which is the down button, the page is not scrolling.

I noticed this behavior in Firefox.

Why does the `return false;` does not stop the button click event on space? What does the javascript spec say about this?

Comment: does it actually say "return fale" in your real code?  If so, that might be your problem.  fale.

Comment: In your code snippet you have "return fale;" -- is this the code as it exists? if so it's a plain typo.

Comment: No I my real code returns false. I actually use this code to intercept other buttons like down, and it works for them.

Comment: Did you try `keyup` like one person did suggest (looks like it was then deleted)? It did work in FF2. I'm surprised to see it gone.

Comment: @crescentfresh: I might have scared them off by saying you didn't need to use keyup. I think I may have messed up.

Comment: I did try to stop it in `keydown` and it works. But this does not answer my question. I want to know why?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Hope this answers your question:

```
<input type="button" value="Press" onkeydown="doOtherStuff(); return false;">
```

`return false;` successfully cancels an event across browsers if called at the end of an event handler attribute in the HTML. This behaviour is not formally specified anywhere as far as I know.

If you instead set an event via an event handler property on the DOM element (e.g. `button.onkeydown = function(evt) {...}`) or using `addEventListener`/`attachEvent` (e.g. `button.addEventListener("keydown", function(evt) {...}, false)`) then just returning `false` from that function does not work in every browser and you need to do the `returnValue` and `preventDefault()` stuff from my other answer. `preventDefault` is specified in the [DOM 2 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-flow-cancelation) and is implemented by most mainstream modern browsers. `returnValue` is IE-specific.

Comment: In my asp.net form, it still fires off the page refresh.

Comment: @Si8: That could happen if your equivalent of `doOtherStuff()` above throws an error.

Answer (score 7):

First, if you're detecting a printable character such as space, you would be better off with the `keypress` event. Secondly, the way to prevent the default action is to call `preventDefault()` on the event in non-IE browsers and set the event's `returnValue` property to `false` in IE.

```
var button = document.getElementById("button");
button.onkeypress = function(evt) {
   evt = evt || window.event;
   var charCode = evt.keyCode || evt.which;
   if (charCode == 32) {
       if (evt.preventDefault) {
           evt.preventDefault();
       } else {
           evt.returnValue = false;
       }
   }
};
```

I'm not a jQuery expert and I assume it takes care of obtaining the event for you:

```
$("button").keypress(function(evt) {
   var charCode = evt.keyCode || evt.which;
   if (charCode == 32) {
       if (evt.preventDefault) {
           evt.preventDefault();
       } else {
           evt.returnValue = false;
       }
   }
});
```

Comment: I tested it, and the `key.preventDefault();` changes nothing in firefox. `keydown` does detect keys, which produce printable characters, so whats wrong with `keydown`?

Comment: OK. What's the HTML that produces the button? Are you sure the keypress handler is being called? In the case of space, you're probably OK to use `keydown` and `keyCode` 32, but in general with printable characters using `keypress` abstracts away any potential difference between keyboards or other input devices by extracting the character that resulted from the keypress rather than a code corresponding to a key on an input device.

Comment: @Tim: the OPs original code sample is valid jQuery for cancelling the event. None of the usual cross-browser code switching is necessary in this case.

Comment: @cresecentfresh: OK. Guess the fact I don't use jQuery is showing through. When someone posts a better answer I'll delete this.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use one attribute in form to stop submit on `enter.<form method="post" onkeydown="return false;">`

as like:    `onkeydown="return false;"` in form attribute

```
<form method="post" onkeydown="return false;"></form>
```