# How to prevent invalid characters from being typed into input fields

Tags: javascript, regex, dom-events

`Onkeydown`, I run the following JavaScript:

```
function ThisOnKeyDown(el) {
   if (el.title == 'textonly') {
       !(/^[A-Za-zÑñ-\s]*$/i).test(el.value) ? el.value = el.value.replace(/[^A-Za-zÑñ-\s]/ig, '') : null;
   }
   if (el.title == 'numbersonly') {
       !(/^[0-9]*$/i).test(el.value) ? el.value = el.value.replace(/[^0-9]/ig, '') : null;
   }
   if (el.title == 'textandnumbers') {
       !(/^[A-Za-zÑñ0-9-\s]*$/i).test(el.value) ? el.value = el.value.replace(/[^A-Za-zÑñ0-9-\s]/ig, '') : null;
   }
}
```

One of these three title attributes is given to various input fields on the page. The code works so far as invalid characters are correctly erased, but not until the next character is entered. I want to find a way to simply deny the invalid input in the first place. I appreciate your help!

**Edit**: I create the events globally. Here's how I do that:

```
      function Globalization() {
      var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
      for (i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
          inputs[i].onfocus = createEventHandler(
              ThisOnFocus, inputs[i]);
          inputs[i].onblur = createEventHandler(
              ThisOnBlur, inputs[i]);
          inputs[i].onkeydown = createEventHandler(
              ThisOnKeyDown, inputs[i]);
          inputs[i].onkeyup = createEventHandler(
              ThisOnKeyUp, inputs[i]);
      }
  }
```

`Globalization()` is run `body.onload`

Therefore, a typical input field has HTML without function calls like this:

```
          <input id="AppFirstName" style="width: 150px;" type="text" maxlength="30" title="textonly"/>
```

Comment: add this function to both `OnKeyPress` and `OnKeyUp`

Comment: Just remember that this kind of validation is not enough and you've always delete this chars server-side.

Comment: @sll, adding to Onkeyup gives a backspace-looking effect. (Onkeypress does the same). What I want to do is deny the input from ever appearing.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

To prevent it from being set in the first place, you can return false on the keydown event handler, thus preventing the event from propagating any further.

I wrote the example below using jQuery, but you can use the same function when binding traditionally.

Though it's important to validate on the server-side as well, client-side validation is important for the sake of user friendliness.

```
$("input.number-only").bind({
    keydown: function(e) {
        if (e.shiftKey === true ) {
            if (e.which == 9) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
        if (e.which > 57) {
            return false;
        }
        if (e.which==32) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: For reference, the key code numbers (9, 57, 32 etc) represent unicode characters, which are listed here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters

Comment: The 'which' property is now deprecated, use 'keyCode' instead: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/keydown

Answer (score 7):

The above code does it says- allows ONLY numbers. You can modify it by adding exception to say BACKSPACE for example like this

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <script>
            function keyispressed(e){
                var charValue= String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode);
                if((isNaN(charValue)) && (e.which != 8 )){ // BSP KB code is 8
                    e.preventDefault();
                }
                return true;
            }
        </script>
    </head>    
    <body>
        <input type="text" onkeydown="return keyispressed(event);"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `var charval` needs to be `var charValue`

Answer (score 5):

You could easily do this in a single html line.

Like this to disallow spaces:

```
<input type="text" onkeypress="return event.charCode != 32">
```

Or this to only allow numbers:

```
<input type="text" onkeypress='return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57'>
```

Just look up the [unicode](https://unicodelookup.com/) of any numbers you want to allow or disallow.

Comment: important to note this only works in the HTML itself: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1648854/4021308 

if you need it as `addEventListener('keydown', ...)` use `preventDefault` if you *don't* want the character allowed

Answer (score 5):

You can replace your input value during the "input" event :

```
// <input oninput=onInput(event) />

const onInput = event => {
    event.target.value = event.target.value.replace(/[^0-9+]/g, '')
}
```

source : https://knplabs.com/en/blog/how2-tips-how-to-restrict-allowed-characters-inside-a-text-input-in-one-line-of-code

Answer (score 3):

```
$('.key-filter').keypress(function () {
    if (event.key.replace(/[^\w\-.]/g,'')=='') event.preventDefault();
});
```

then add the key-filter class to your input if using jquery
or

```
<input type="text" onkeypress="if (event.key.replace(/[^\w\-.]/g,'')=='') event.preventDefault();" />
```

just put the charaters you want to allow inside the [] after the ^.
this allows all letters numbers _ - and .

Comment: I would rather use regex test() method instead of replace(). Also, returning false is enough.

Answer (score 1):

i found this solution in: http://help.dottoro.com/ljlkwans.php

works as intended.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function FilterInput (event) {
        var keyCode = ('which' in event) ? event.which : event.keyCode;

        isNumeric = (keyCode >= 48 /* KeyboardEvent.DOM_VK_0 */ && keyCode <= 57 /* KeyboardEvent.DOM_VK_9 */) ||
                    (keyCode >= 96 /* KeyboardEvent.DOM_VK_NUMPAD0 */ && keyCode <= 105 /* KeyboardEvent.DOM_VK_NUMPAD9 */);
        modifiers = (event.altKey || event.ctrlKey || event.shiftKey);
        return !isNumeric || modifiers;
    }
</script>

< body>
The following text field does not accept numeric input:
<input type="text" onkeydown="return FilterInput (event)" />< /body>
```

it allows text and !"#$%& but you can adjust it adding these to the validationto only allow numbers by removing the ! in the return

Answer (score 1):

Code is useful for preventing user from typing any other character except number.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <script>
            function keyispressed(e){
                var charval= String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode);
                if(isNaN(charval)){
                    return false;
                }
                return true;
            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <input type="text" onkeydown="return keyispressed(event);"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Worth noting: This code also prevents things like backspace and shif+arrow selection.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It helped me realize I needed to return the function in the onkeydown in order for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Run your code against the onkeyup event and not the onkeydown event.  This way you can access the result of the very last keystroke where as the onkeyup event executes as a key is pressed without knowing its result.

Comment: It shouldn't.  I use this event on my own application and it works just fine.  To see what I am doing just go to the following link and start typing code.  http://prettydiff.com/?m=beautify

Comment: Not sure even which field to look at on that page, but it won't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Here's An easy way. Allows only numbers

```
const isNumberKey = (e: any) =>
{
    if (e.key.length > 1)
    {
        return true;
    }

    const charCode = e.key.charCodeAt(0);

    if (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)
    {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`pattern`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/pattern) attribute for input elements can be used as an alternative when validation is considered sufficient and is not really imperative to prevent a set of characters to be typed.

In your case for example the following should work (do note your pattern have an error with a not escaped dash `-` before `\s`)

```html
<input 
    pattern="^[A-Za-zÑñ\-\s]*$" 
    id="AppFirstName" style="width: 150px;" type="text" maxlength="30" title="textonly"
/>
```