# HTML input text don't allow colon ( : )

Tags: html, input

I have this basic input text:

`<input type="text"/>`

I would like to know if is possible to prevent inserting a colon. If the user presses " : " I would like that nothing appear on the input text.

Comment: You'll need some Javascript to the rescue : see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8282266/how-to-prevent-invalid-characters-from-being-typed-into-input-fields

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it:

```js
function removeInvalid(text) {

  document.getElementById('noColon').value = text.replace(/\;+/, "");

  text = final;

}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="noColon" onkeyup="removeInvalid(this.value)" onchange="removeInvalid(this.value)" placeholder="colons are not allowed" />
```

I hope this helps!