# Prevent a character from being entered in ALL text boxes on a page ASP.net

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have a panel that is used for programmatically creating textboxes. When a user clicks save, the values in these texboxes need to be concatenated and I need a character to separate each value. For this, I am using a comma (ASCII code 44). Because I am using a comma, I want to prevent any other commas from being entered in any of the textboxes in my textbox list. What would be the best way to go about doing this?

Comment: well, you can probably just remove or replace all commas from the textbox values after your user sends a POST request and then concatenate with commas. if you want to add extra flavor, you might add an onkeyup function to your text boxes where if the character added is a comma, you return false.

Comment: I don't have good advise other than to mention that when we need a good separator, we use a pipe | because it's not generally anything other people want to type. And this link to a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8282266/how-to-prevent-invalid-characters-from-being-typed-into-input-fields

Comment: Note: you don't control the client, so you can't *rely* on anything that you do in the UI. Your server should check values, even if the UI disallows it.

Answer (score 0):

If jQuery is an option you can do

```
$(".no-comma-textbox").on("keydown", function(e){
    if (e.which == 188){
      e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

And all your textboxes should have `class="no-comma-textbox"`.

(note: when I tested this 188 seems to be the correct value to use for comma at least in Chrome)

Answer (score 0):

Try using `oninput` event attached to `document` , `String.prototype.slice()`

```js
document.oninput = function(e) {
  if (e.target.value.slice(-1) === ",") {
    e.target.value = e.target.value.slice(0, -1)
  }
}

var input = document.createElement("input");
input.setAttribute("type", "text");
input.setAttribute("name", "input2");
document.body.appendChild(input);
```

```html
  <input type="text" name="input0" />
  <input type="text" name="input1" />
```