# How to prevent invalid input for input field

Tags: php, jquery, html

How to prevent input type number from undefined value. For example as follows:

[image: Image example]

so how to prevent input plus or minus?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8282266/how-to-prevent-invalid-characters-from-being-typed-into-input-fields

Comment: Use `type="text"` with `pattern="[0-9]*"`, or `pattern="(-?[0-9]+)?"` (or even.... just write the regex you need to validate with.)

Comment: input type number in html5 auto prevent from string but how to prevent from plus and mines in beetween number

Comment: I use tostring() function and search string but dont working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Block  '+' and '-' key on key press

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="parent">
<input type="number" onkeypress='return event.charCode != 43 && event.charCode != 45'></input>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: how to block just plus and mines key on keypress event?

Comment: block charCode  43(+)  and 45(-)

Comment: code updated :)

Comment: It still allows `e`  and does not allow a `-`/`+` in the initial position.

Comment: <input type="number" onkeypress='return event.charCode != 43 && event.charCode != 45 && event.charCode != 69 && event.charCode != 101'></input>

Answer (score 0):

You have to write some javascript code for achieving your goal.

```
document.querySelector("input").addEventListener("keypress", function (evt) {
    if (evt.which < 48 || evt.which > 57)
    {
        evt.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

keypress fires on the input element, and bubbles to document.