# Is there a way to capture Letters in a type="number" input field?

Tags: html, input, text, types, numbers

I have this input field:

```
<input type="number" class="col-sm-12" id="scanner" autofocus>
```

right now, you can scan anything into it and if the scanned data includes anything besides numbers, it strips them off.
This is for an Android webView mobile app and when this scanner has focus, we want to only show the numbers keypad, which is why its a "number" type.

Anyone know how I can capture the letters if even though the input field is of type "number" without changing it back to type="text"?

Comment: To help us answer this and avoid an [XY Problem situation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/43452), could you include something on why you need this?

Comment: Yes, I am building a feature to scan barcodes. The barcodes should be numbers only, but users sometimes scan barcodes that include letters and we want to capture that without showing the alphabetic keypad.

Answer (score 2):

No, the `numbers` attribute of an `input` field strips the values and from what I've found these cannot be caught as there is an implicit `regex` being applied to the `input` field.

However, you can try to make your own validation & catch the letters if they're of value to you.

See below how to achieve this.

Firstly, set the field type attribute back to `text`, i.e.

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter Number"/>
```

You can get only letters from a string using the regex:

```
/[^a-zA-Z]+/g
```

You can get only numbers from a string using the regex:

```
/\D/g
```

Apply an `onkeyup` event to monitor the input to the field:

```
onkeyup="validate(this)
```

The final solution monitors the `onkeyup` event, strips the letters out and only allows the numbers to remain. However, it catches the letters in a `var` for later use.

```html
<script>
function validate(element) {
    var letters = element.value.replace(/[^a-zA-Z]+/g, '');
    var numbers = element.value.replace(/\D/g,'');
    element.value = numbers;
   
}
</script>
<input type="text" onkeyup="validate(this)" placeholder="Enter Number"/>
```

Also see the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o7jm81nk/)

**EDIT:**

If you don't like how the letters are appearing and then immediately being deleted from the input, you will need to monitor the `keydown` event and match each letter/symbol to their keyCode.

An implementation of this can be found here: [How to prevent invalid characters from being typed into input fields](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12642926/11700321)

The full list of Javascript Key Codes can be found here: [Javascript Char Codes (Key Codes)](https://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes)

Comment: Its a great solution that would have solved my problem if I didn't have to display a numbers keypad. Will definitely use this in another function of mine. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Input fields of type number allow the use of the letter e (representing an exponent). So you should be able to test your method by typing the letter e.