# How to restrict specific characters in a text box?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to restrict single and double quotations within the text box of a form ( " or '). I've researched and seen JS to only allow alphanumeric and so on, but nothing to restrict a specific character exactly.

I'm fine with it not allowing it to be typed or to use an alert pop-up upon validation. Both work for me.

See code Below:

```js
function validateForm() {
  let x = document.forms["commentform"]["commentbox"].value;
  if (x == "") {
    alert("form must be filled out");
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<div align="center">
  <h2>Comment Expiration Demand</h2>
  <form name="commentform" action="/action_page.php" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
    <input type="text" size="50" maxlength="40" name="commentbox" id="commentbox">
    <br> 40 characters max length, no single or double quotations ( " or ' )
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" id="submit">
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the code you’ve already written in an attempt to meet the requirements you describe, in accordance with [ask]?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to prevent invalid characters from being typed into input fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8282266/how-to-prevent-invalid-characters-from-being-typed-into-input-fields)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you are directly **comparing the value** of the input field. Instead you want to search for a string in that value.

Also, `""` is an empty string. You need to use `"'"` for `'` and `'"'` for `"`.

```js
function validateForm() {
    let x = document.forms["commentform"]["commentbox"].value;
    if (x.indexOf("'") > -1 || x.indexOf('"') > -1) {
        alert("form must be filled out");
        return false;
    }
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div align="center">
        <h2>Comment Expiration Demand</h2>
        <form name="commentform" action="/action_page.php" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
            <input type="text" size="50" maxlength="40" name="commentbox" id="commentbox">
            <br>
            40 characters max length, no single or double quotations ( " or ' )
            <br>
            <br>
            <input type="submit" value="submit" id="submit"> 
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: That's actually "" because the box can't be empty. I'm also wanting to restrict quotations

Comment: Ok, So I guess you can combine that condition with the two I have given and let us know how it turns out

Comment: Combining them works! Thank you. I upvoted this, but it said I needed more reputation to cast a vote...

Answer (score 0):

You can make an on input event to prevent typing [" , '] and if typed alert will pop and the input box will be emptied with creating an empty array and add every character added in it then check if the array contains [" or '] if so empty the text box and show an alert

```js
var input = document.querySelector("#commentbox");

input.addEventListener("input", (e) => {
  //SAVE THE INPUT VALUE
  ele = e.target.value;
  //CREATE EMPTY ARRAY
  var charArr = [];
  //MAP THROUGH THE INPUT VALUE AND ADD EVERY CHAR INTO THE EMPTY ARRAY
  for (let i = 0; i < ele.length; i++) {
    charArr.push(ele[i]);
  }
  //IF THE ARRAY CONTAINS YOU RISTRICTED CHARS SHOW AN ALERT AND EMPTY THE INPUT BOX
  if (charArr.includes(`"`) || charArr.includes(`'`)) {
    alert(`Can not Put ( " , ' ) as an input`);
    e.target.value = "";
  } else {
    //DO YOUR FUNCTION
  }
});
```

```html
<div>
  <h2>Comment Expiration Demand</h2>
  <form name="commentform" action="/action_page.php" onsubmit="returnvalidateForm()" method="post">
    <input type="text" size="50" maxlength="40" name="commentbox" id="commentbox">
    <br> 40 characters max length, no single or double quotations ( " or ' )
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" id="submit">
  </form>
</div>
```