# Explanation input only numeric

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new in html and javascript, coming from C#. 
Now I have created an input field, which must only accept numeric input. Like so:

```
<input name="numemp" type="text" id="numemp" value="<%=numberofemp%>" maxlength="10" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" />
```

And I found this javascript:

```
function isNumberKey(evt) 
{
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode;
    if (charCode != 46 && charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) 
    {
        return false;
    }
    else 
    {
        return true;
    }      
}
```

This is not clear for me, I get it that the code checks the pressed key is numeric. And if it is numeric it returns true. But where does the code ignores the input? I only see a return false when this happend...

Comment: `return false;` means ignore this key input.

Comment: In javascript `return false` means that default action of event (in this case - write character into input) will not be called.

Comment: you can check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1639338/why-does-returning-false-in-they-keydown-callback-does-not-stop-the-button-click .

Comment: Thanks, it makes a lot clearer

Answer (score 0):

Yes indeed it doesn't ignore the input it just says whether it's a number or not, I think you don't need to use this function :

You only need HTML5 pattern to do it `pattern="[0-9]+"` and it will be automatically managed:

```
<input name="numemp" type="text" id="numemp" value="<%=numberofemp%>" maxlength="10" pattern="[0-9]+" />
```

Take a look at [HTML  pattern Attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_pattern.asp) for further information.

Comment: This does not answer the question, which asked for an explanation for some code. It could have been posted as a comment.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela Yes you're right, but I've only  thought it'll be a better solution  for this issue