# How to invoke a method when enter is pressed in a p:inputText

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a JSF ajax keydown event linked to an event listener in a backing bean.

The code in the JSF file is below.

```
<p:inputText value="#{someBean.value}>
<p:ajax event="keydown" listener="#{someBean.keyDownEvent}" />
</p:inputText>
```

I want to get "Enter" button event code. When I click on enter I need to perform some specific event on server side. How can I get that event code using ajax call?

Comment: PrimeFaces has no specific key event handler at the bean side, so you need to use the onkeydown attribute and pass the key to a remoteCommand function to pass it to your bean. But why would you want to Ajax on each keydown?

Comment: Where would you want to get the event code ? At the client side or in the baking bean ?

Comment: use  'onkeyup="jsfunction(event)" ' and check the keycode in your jsfunction and call your listener method .

Comment: the even "code" is keydown. you assigned this event to this handler.  what other do you want to know?

Comment: I want to get "Enter" button event code. When I click on enter I need to perform some specific event on server side. How can I get that event code using ajax call?

Comment: none of the answers solves your problem?

Comment: Did one of the answers solve your problem? Then please accept it.

Answer (score 6):

Since you only want to perform an action when the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key is pressed, I really would not send every key to the backend using an Ajax call and there determine what key was pressed.

Simply check for enter in the front end, and if it was detected **just then** call the backend using a [`p:remoteCommand`](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajax/remoteCommand.xhtml). But there is a catch here. Enter woud submit the entire form by default, so make sure to return `false` when the `keyCode` for enter (13) is found.

Then, [validation](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajax/validation.xhtml). If you would happen to have multiple inputs in your form you might run into validation errors. So setup the remote command to only process itself and the input where the enter key was pressed. Optionally, you might want to update the [`p:message`](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/message/messages.xhtml) field linked to the input to show any validation errors.

This will lead to:

```
<p:remoteCommand name="myRemCo"
                 action="#{someBean.action}"
                 process="@this myInput"
                 update="myInputMessage"/>

<p:inputText id="myInput"
             value="#{someBean.value}"
             onkeydown="if (event.keyCode === 13) { myRemCo(); return false; }"
             required="true"/>
<p:message for="myInput" id="myInputMessage"/>
```

Note that I put `required="true"` there to demonstrate updating the message in case you press enter when the input is still empty.

See also:

- [Default action to execute when pressing enter in a form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5485851/default-action-to-execute-when-pressing-enter-in-a-form)
- [PrimeFaces disable submit on pressing enter key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28116894/primefaces-disable-submit-on-pressing-enter-key)
- [.keyCode vs. .which](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4471582/javascript-keycode-vs-which)
- http://caniuse.com/#search=keycode
- https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/misc/defaultCommand.xhtml

Answer (score 0):

If you need the code of the pressed key then here is an example. It assign an event handler to the `inText` input control. Here gets the code of the pressed key from the event object and call the `onKeyPressed` method of the controller by `<p:remoteCommand>`. The key code passed as a request parameter. The key code displayed in the `outText` output control as a test.

The facelet:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">
  <h:head>
    <title>Facelet Title</title>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        function jsKeyPressedHandler(event)
        {
          var kc = event.which || event.keyCode;
          rc( [{ name : 'keyCode', value : Number( kc ) }] );
        }
      </script>

</h:head>
  <h:body>
    <h:form id="myForm">
    <p:remoteCommand name="rc" update="outText" actionListener="#{myBean.onKeyPressed}" />
    <p:inputText id="inText" value="#{myBean.text1}" onkeypress="jsKeyPressedHandler( event )"/>
    <h:outputText id="outText" value="#{myBean.text2}"/>
    </h:form>
  </h:body>

  </h:body>
</html>
```

The controller:

```
package x;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.view.ViewScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;

@Named( value = "myBean" )
@ViewScoped
public class MyBean implements Serializable
{
  private String text1;
  private String text2;

  public String getText1() { return text1; }      
  public void setText1( String text1_ ) { text1 = text1_; }      
  public String getText2() { return text2; }      
  public void setText2( String text2_ ) { text2 = text2_; }      

  public void onKeyPressed()
  {
    Map<String,String> reqParams = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap();
    String c = (String) reqParams.get( "keyCode" );
    if ( text2 != null )
      text2 += c;
    else
      text2 = c;  
  }
}
```

Comment: There is no need to use `which` anymore. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4471582/javascript-keycode-vs-which

Comment: This does an ajax call on each keyPress... I would advice against it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use default command component of primefaces . check it out