# Keypress in text input preventing typing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a text input that I want to execute a function when enter is pressed. I used if condition to determine if enter is pressed but this causes the user not to be able to type in the input box. What can I put in the else condition to allow them to type normally?

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sbnLupc4/)

```
function addItem(e) {   
    e.preventDefault();                         // Prevent form being submitted
    var text = $('input:text').val();           // Get value of text input
    var itemArr = text.split(',');                                                              
    var lngth = itemArr.length                  

    for(i = 0; i < lngth; i++)                  
    {
        $list.append('<li>' + itemArr[i] + '</li>');    // Add item to end of the list
        updateCount();                                  // Update the count
    } // End loop

    $('#addItems').val('');                         // Empty the text input
    return false;
}

$('#addItems').keypress(function(e) {
    if(e.which == 13) {
        addItem();
    }
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove `return false;`  from the keypress function.

```
$('#addItems').keypress(function(e) {
    if(e.which == 13) {
        addItem();
    }   
    else {
        return true;
    }

    return false;   
});
```

Comment: If I do that the page refreshes when I hit enter, which I don't want

Comment: @Shniper then use else with return true

Comment: Still refreshing when I press enter, with your code

Comment: <input type="button" value="Add"> use this instead of  <input type="submit" value="Add">

Comment: @Shniper check this Link http://jsbin.com/weqofinoye/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 0):

Jusr remove return false from the keypress event

You can see this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1639338/why-does-returning-false-in-the-keydown-callback-does-not-stop-the-button-click)

> `return false;` successfully cancels an event across browsers if called at the end of an event handler attribute in the HTML.

and to prevent form from form being submitted, you can add onsubmit="return false" to the form

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Aya_Salama/r08kgwna/)

Comment: @Shniper i think this may solve your form submission problem