# Disable enter key postback only when cursor is in input field

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, dialogflow-es

I'm working on a user control to display a chat box for Dialogflow and I want enter to submit the string entered in the box to a JavaScript event instead of the code behind. I want to be able to add this user control to any of my .net pages, which contain buttons and inputs of their own. Unfortunately, this requirement prevents me from taking the easy route and disabling the enter key submit behavior in the form.

Here is the HTML for the control:

```
<div id="mainWrapper">
    <div id="result">

    </div>
    <div id="inputField">
        <input placeholder="Ask me a question" id="query" type="text" />
    </div>
    <asp:HiddenField ID="access" runat="server" />
</div>
```

The only thing I currently have my code behind doing is assigning a value to that hidden field on page load. I have tried changing the input to `asp:TextBox`, and adding `UseSubmitBehavior="False"`, but it still causes a postback. I have also added `return false;` to the JavaScript I am using, but it seems like the postback occurs before it runs.

Here is the relevant JavaScript:

```
(function () {
    "use strict";
    var token, queryInput, resultDiv;
    var ENTER_KEY_PRESS = 13;
    var client;
    window.onload = init;

    function init() {
        token = document.getElementByID("<%= access.ClientID %>").value;
        queryInput = document.getElementById("query");
        resultDiv = document.getElementById("result");

        queryInput.addEventListener("keydown", keyDown);
    }

    function keyDown(event) {
        if (event.which === ENTER_KEY_PRESS) {
            console.log("Enter pressed")
            var queryValue = queryInput.value;
            queryInput.value = "";

            sendTextToDIalogflow(value)
                .then(function (response) {
                    var result;
                    try {
                        result = response.result.fulfillment.speech;
                    } catch (error) {
                        result = "error: " + error.message;
                    }
                    console.log(result)
                })
                .catch(function (err) {
                    console.log("Whoops, something went wrong: " + err.message);
                });
        }
        else {
            console.log("Enter not pressed")
        }
    }
    return false;
})();
```

How do I prevent the enter key from triggering a postback when the cursor is in the textbox without doing the same for other asp.net controls on the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might not be the only thing, I notice you aren't following your pattern on finding the element ID:

```
queryInput = document.getElementById("<%= query.ClientID %>");
resultDiv = document.getElementById("<%= result.ClientID %>");
```

And on the key press, you need to prevent the enter from propogating.  So here's a keydown change:

```
function keyDown(event) {
    if (event.which === ENTER_KEY_PRESS) {
        console.log("Enter pressed")
        var queryValue = queryInput.value;
        queryInput.value = "";

        sendTextToDIalogflow(value)
            .then(function (response) {
                var result;
                try {
                    result = response.result.fulfillment.speech;
                } catch (error) {
                    result = "error: " + error.message;
                }
                console.log(result)
            })
            .catch(function (err) {
                console.log("Whoops, something went wrong: " + err.message);
            });

         // ADDED CODE
         // REFERENCE - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1639338/why-does-returning-false-in-they-keydown-callback-does-not-stop-the-button-click
         if (event.preventDefault) {
             event.preventDefault();
         } else {
             event.returnValue = false;
         }
         // END ADDED CODE
    }
    else {
        console.log("Enter not pressed")
    }
}
```

Comment: I just added the code you gave to the function and it doesn't seem like it's stopping the postback.

Comment: it should have been event. not e., since you were using event as your parameter...i updated it...id also recommend your init function goes to the bottom

Comment: i added a fiddle with the concepts so you can see that in action...obviously in my fiddle i couldnt use the asp.net client id stuff or your custom function stuff - https://jsfiddle.net/eYzSX/178/