# convert from "onkeypress" to "addeventlistener("keypress",()=>{})

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I have the following line of JS written into my html on an input tag. I'm in class learning about separation of concerns and that we shouldn't put JS into our html. I've been trying to figure out a way to convert this lines:

```
onkeypress="return (event.charCode >= 65 && event.charCode <= 90) || (event.charCode >= 97 && event.charCode <= 122) || event.charCode == 32;"
```

To something like this:

```
document.querySelector("#login-first-name").addEventListener("keypress",function(event){
  return (event.charCode >= 65 && event.charCode <= 90) || (event.charCode >= 97 && event.charCode <= 122) || event.charCode == 32;
});
```

Any insight would be great.

Comment: an arrow function doesn't have bindings to the `this`, you should use regular `function(){}`

Comment: @artanik - thanks for the quick feedback. I believe I tried ``function() {}`` the first time. I'll try again! :)

Comment: and `event` is a parameter of a callback function, and you have zero params in `onkeypress`, this should be something like `("keypress", function(event) {})`

Comment: Also you need to add parameter `event` like `addEventListener("keypress", (event)=>{` and if you want to use `this` then use `function` like `addEventListener("keypress", function(event) {`

Comment: @artanik -- that worked for the 2nd one (using ``this``). Still no luck with the first one using the return statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add parameter `event` like `addEventListener("keypress", (event)=>{` and if you want to use `this` then use `function` like `addEventListener("keypress", function(event) {`

After some research found that with `document.querySelector("#login-first-name").addEventListener("keypress"` need to assign `event.returnValue` instead of `return`. [For more information refer this.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1639984/9695286) Updated code also.

Check it below.

```js
document.querySelector("#login-first-name").addEventListener("keypress", (event) => {
  event.returnValue = (event.charCode >= 65 && event.charCode <= 90) || (event.charCode >= 97 && event.charCode <= 122) || event.charCode == 32;
});

document.querySelector("#login-first-name").addEventListener("keyup", function() {
  this.value = this.value.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + this.value.slice(1);
});
```

```html
<input id='login-first-name' />
```

Comment: thank you for the response. I added ``event`` like your code suggests, but it still isn't working. This code is supposed to prevent non-alpha characters and numbers. It should only accept letters. The code snippet allows non-alpha characters too :(

Comment: The `event` isn't required [since it is a global property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/event). But it's nevertheless still recommended to explicitly list it as a parameter.

Comment: @Ivar, OMG, I am using it for so long and today I come to know that it is a `global property`. Thanks man for your comment. I learn something today. Really appreciate it.